# How to use PHP and CURL for going to login-page

Tags: php, curl, http-post, libcurl

For loging to this [website](http://www.chronodrive.com/)

We should choose a code postal and then go to [this page](https://www.chronodrive.com/login)

with using CURL, i can choose a code postal ( city)

```
$shopId= 1039;
$ch = curl_init("http://www.chronodrive.com/prehome");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.chronodrive.com/home?shopId=". $shopId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output) ;
```

My problem is going to login page. i get the parametres of cookie:

```
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $server_output, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }


    $jsessionid =  $cookies['JSESSIONID'] ;
    $sessionStatId =  $cookies['SessionStatId'] ;
    $chronoShop =  $cookies['chronoShop'] ;
    $chronoCookie =  $cookies['chronoCookie'] ;
```

and set them in headers and use this code for going to loging page

```
    $ch2 = curl_init('http://www.chronodrive.com/home');

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,"www.chronodrive.com/home.home.header.menuconnect.loginbutton:login");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $headers = [
                  'Host: www.chronodrive.com', #ok1
                  'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', #OK1
                  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',  #OK1
                  'Referer: www.chronodrive.com/home', #OK1
                  'DNT: 1', #OK1
                  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0', #ok1
                  'Cookie: Cookie: JSESSIONID='.$jsessionid.'; tc_cj_v2=%5Ecl_%5Dny%5B%5D%5D_mmZZZZZZKNRKRJKNSPKNQZZZ%5D; ADRUM=s=1481801501302&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chronodrive.com%2Fhome%3F0; chronoShop='.$chronoShop.'; chronoCookie='.$chronoCookie.'; popinComm=1; sto__session=1481800240770; sto__count=4',
                  'Connection: keep-alive' #OK1
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $server_output2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
    var_dump($server_output2) ;
```

but i redirected to the first page ( where we didn't choose Code postal !! )

i tried also
 `curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`
but i'm redirected to the first page.

My question is how to get login page.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful but https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html mentions ways of having cURL handle cookies for you.

Comment: I used CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR but it doesn't save cookies file, it's not problem of permission, i checked it